# Best way to filter out emails and domains in python

Tags: python, regex, email, filtering, email-validation

I have a list of emails and domains which I am trying to filter out as a blacklist

For email it is easy, since I can simply compare the emails directly but for domains, emails with subdomains etc need to be matched as well.

so for the foo.com domain, I would need to filter out

```
x@foo.com
x@subdomain.foo.com
```

How is this typically done? Via Regex? Splitting the email into the appropriate strings?

Comment: is it a long list of domains?

Comment: not right now, but I expect it to grow quite a bit. that is why I am storing them in a db vs a config file

Comment: if the list is long, what is the better way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm thinking the easiest way to go about this is to use the [string method `ends_with`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith).  This method works as follows:

```
>>> blacklisted = 'foo.com'
>>> email = 'x@foo.com'
>>> email.endswith('foo.com')
True
>>> email = 'x@subdomain.foo.com'
>>> email.endswith('foo.com')
True
```

So, this will return true if the domain, or email, or whatever ends with `'foo.com'`. As you can see, this will include all subdomains of `'foo.com'`. Conveniently, you can also pass a tuple to `endswith`, so if you construct a tuple of your blacklisted domains you could do something like this:

```
>>> blacklisted = ('foo.com', 'bar.com')
>>> email = 'x@bar.com'
>>> email.endswith(blacklisted)
True
```

This will even have the benefit of being able to blacklist some subdomains, but not others.

```
>>> blacklisted = ('foo.com', 'bar.com', 'sub.baz.net')
>>> email_bad = 'x@sub.baz.net'
>>> email_bad.endswith(blacklisted)
True
>>> email_good = 'x@good.baz.net'
>>> email_good.endswith(blacklisted)
False
```

**Edit:** In response to Avaris's comment:

In order to make sure you don't end up with this situation:

```
>>> blacklisted = ('bar.com', 'baz.com')
>>> email = 'x@foobar.com'
>>> email.endswith(blacklisted)
True
```

You can included in your blacklisted list both `'.bar.com'` and `'@bar.com'`. The result of which is

```
>>> blacklisted = ('.bar.com', '@bar.com', '.baz.com', '@baz.com')
>>> email = 'x@foobar.com'
>>> email.endswith(blacklisted)
False
```

This is obviously more work. At this point I would say this method versus regex is a matter of preference. While I try to avoid regex at all costs, it might be the way to go for you.

Comment: `x@foobar.com` will come out as blacklisted if you have `bar.com` as unwanted.

Comment: Yikes, I didn't think of that. Can you see a simple fix, or is this idea toast?

Comment: Maybe, you could put both `@bar.com` and `.bar.com` in the unwanted list instead of just `bar.com`.

Comment: I just thought of that. I'll update the answer, although that's getting close to the point where I would just use a regex.

Comment: would this become inefficient if I have a large number of blacklisted emails?

Comment: would you do this differently if I told you my list was stored in a db?

Comment: The complexity of this should be linear, O(n), in the number of blacklists entries. It's not incredibly efficient, but you won't get better with regexes. What do you consider large? If you're talking hundreds of millions of entries, and you need results in less than a millisecond, you'll have to do something more complicated like a suffix tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

Comment: As for the db, that would depend on the size of the list. If it fits easily in memory, I would probably just suck it out of the db once, and use this method.

Comment: yeah...it should...but I'm using sqlalchemy...I guess I'd have to cache my results? I wonder how I can do that

Comment: Caching would be another question entirely :).

Answer (score 1):

This would be the simplest way I can think of:

```
>>> f = 'foo@subdomain.bar.com'
>>> '.'.join(f.split('.')[-2:])
'bar.com'
```

It doesn't use a regex, it's only one line, very readable, it will pull out the domain name, and has the added benefit of not caring if the domain is a .com, .net, or whatever.

Then you'd just check the extracted domain against your blacklisted table.

EDIT:
Ok, for .co.uk domains et al

```
>>> import re
>>> def get_addr(email_addr):
        parts = re.split(r'[\@\.]', email_addr)
        return '.'.join(parts[(-3 if parts[-2] == 'co' else -2):])
>>> get_addr('foo@subdomain.bar.com')
'bar.com'
>>> get_addr('foo@subdomain.bar.co.uk')
'bar.co.uk'
>>> get_addr('foo@bar.com')
'bar.com'
```

EDIT:
@Wilduck pointed out that there may be use cases where you want to filter out specific subdoamins, but not others (ie 'community.ebay.co.uk'). I figured, you may want to blacklist specific email addresses too without needing a separate table (ie exgirlfriend@gmail.com). Here's my solution:

```
>>> def is_in_blacklist(addr):
...     #check if addr is in your list or db table
...     return True or False

>>> def addr_is_blacklisted(addr):
...     if not addr: return False
...     if is_in_blacklist(addr):
...         return True
...     sliced = '.'.join(addr.split('@' if '@' in addr else '.')[1:])
...     return addr_is_blacklisted(sliced)
```

So it's deconstructing the email address from beginning to end and checking each part against your blacklist. Obviously you can't get an answer with a single query, but you can filter by single email addresses, to subdomains, to domains, and all the way down to top level domains if you're so inclined. You'll have 3-4 queries per email on average, and you won't kill yourself if you have a huge blacklist.

Comment: foo@subdomain.bar.co.uk? Also, why would you want to _necessarily_ blacklist both whitehouse.com and whitehouse.gov?

Comment: yeah, emails need to be international

Comment: And it will also fail for `foo@bar.com`.

Comment: Ah, didn't think of those. Ok, the new edit will handle 'foo@bar.com', 'foo@subdomain.bar.com', and 'foo@subdomain.bar.co.uk'

Comment: @Wilduck, this wouldn't cause both whitehouse.com and whitehouse.gov to be blacklisted. The function pulls out the email's domain name which you would compare against a table. If whitehouse.com was blacklisted, whitehouse.gov emails would not be affected.

Comment: You're right about that, I misinterpreted your original answer. Still, while I'm sure this would work fine in most cases, it breaks down if you need to check against a blacklist that contains subdomains, like if I wanted to block all emails from `community.ebay.co.uk` but not from `ebay.co.uk`.

Comment: Good point. Ok, I think I've come up with a solution that will give you that control / granularity, without destroying performance. Check my last edit

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
.*foo\.com$
```

does it work?

Comment: is regex a sensible way to go?

Comment: should I be storing the regex instead of the domain?

Comment: It should be noted that this suffers from the same problem that Avaris pointed out about `str.endswith`. Namely, that it will match `'x@barfoo.com'`.